# Clean data with a mapping table

Tags: r

I am trying to clean data with a mapping table and looking for the best way to achieve that.

Here's some sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(Q1 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Non"),
                 Q2 = c("Non", "No", "Oui"))
```

I have a mapping table for converting those answers to TRUE/FALSE

```
map <- data.frame(answer  = c("Yes", "Oui", "No", "Non"),
                  mapping = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))
```

This is what I want as output

```
out <- data.frame(Q1 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
                  Q2 = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE))
```

I've tried this approach:

```
out <- merge(df,  map, by.x = "Q1", by.y = "answer", all.x = TRUE)
out <- merge(out, map, by.x = "Q2", by.y = "answer", all.x = TRUE)
out <- out[ , 3:4]
names(out) <- c("Q1", "Q2")
```

But this seems kind-of clumsy as you create new columns, delete the old and then rename. Is there a better way to do this; like an option to merge into an existing column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `plyr::mapvalues`.

```
> mapvalues(df$Q1, from = map$answer, to = map$mapping)
The following `from` values were not present in `x`: Oui, No
[1] TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
Levels: FALSE TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Or use `Map` or something similar to loop through `df` and grab the corresponding `o`utput from the `m`apping variable.

```
Map(function(x,m,o) o[match(x,m)], df, map["answer"], map["mapping"])
#$Q1
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#
#$Q2
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Wrap it all in `data.frame` if you need to convert the result.

Comment: Nice, I'll have a play with that too.